# Merge txt files in a folder and replacing characters in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, merge, io

I have a doubt about how to do to continue the code, I need to take all files from a folder and merge them in 1 file with another text format.

Example:

The Input files are of text format like this:

```
"{'nr': '3173391045', 'data': '27/12/2017'}"
"{'nr': '2173391295', 'data': '05/01/2017'}"
"{'nr': '5173351035', 'data': '07/03/2017'}"
```

The Output files must be lines like this:

```
"3173391045","27/09/2017"
"2173391295","05/01/2017"
"5173351035","07/03/2017"
```

This is my working code, it's working for merge and taking out the blank lines

```
import glob2
import datetime

filenames=glob2.glob("*.txt")

with open(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S-%f")+".SAI", 'w') as file:
    for filename in filenames:
        with open(filename,"r") as f:
            file.write(f.read())
```

I'm trying something with .replace but is not working, I get syntax errors or blank files

```
filedata = filedata.replace("{", "") for line in filedata
```

Comment: use `json.loads` to read each line into a dictionary instead of trying to lamely parse your input string.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: unfortunately, lines are not in valid json format: strings are enclosed in single quote while json requires double quotes...

Comment: thats the chalenge!

Answer (score 1):

If your input files had contained valid JSON strings, the correct way would have been to parse the lines as JSON and write them back in csv. As strings are enclosed in single quotes (`'`) they are rejected by the json module of the Python library, and my advice is to use a regex to parse them. Code could become:

```
import glob2
import datetime
import csv
import re

# the regex to parse the line
rx = re.compile(r".*'nr'\s*:\s*'(\d+)'.*'data'\s*:\s*'([/\d]+)'")

filenames=glob2.glob("*.txt")

with open(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S-%f")+".SAI", 'w') as file:
    wr = csv.writer(file, quoting = csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for filename in filenames:
        with open(filename,"r") as f:
            for line in f:                  # process line by line
                m = rx.match(line)
                wr.writerow(m.groups())
```

Comment: This one Works Great! I'm just looking how to take out the empty lines in regex documentation.
Thank you very Much @Serge Ballesta

Answer (score 0):

With a few tweaks, the input data can be coerced into a form suitable for JSON parsing:

```
from datetime import datetime
import json
import glob2
import csv

with open(datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S-%f")+".SAI", 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for filename in glob2.glob('*.txt'):
        with open(filename) as f_input:
            for row in f_input:
                row_dict = json.loads(row.strip('"\n').replace("'", '"'))
                csv_output.writerow([row_dict['nr'], row_dict['data']])
```

Giving you:

```
"3173391045","27/12/2017"
"2173391295","05/01/2017"
"5173351035","07/03/2017"
```

Note, in Python 3.x the output file should be opened with `newline=''`. Without this, extra blank lines can appear in the output file.

Comment: I don't see why but the end result is an empty file @Martin Evans, but thanks for aswer

Comment: If your files in are sub-folders, then you will need to use your `glob2`. I have updated the script.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Merging/pmerge.py", line 13, in <module>
    csv_output.writerow([row_dict['nr'], row_dict['data']])
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Yes, i'm using 3.6.3.

Answer (score 0):

using regex/replaces to parse those strings is dangerous. You could always stumble on a data containing the delimiter, the comma, etc..

And in this case, even if `json` cannot read those lines,`ast.literal_eval` can without any modification whatsoever:

```
import ast
with open("output.csv",newline="") as fw:
    cw = csv.writer(fw)
    for filename in filenames:
        with open(filename) as f:
            for line in f:
                d = ast.literal_eval(line)
                cw.writerow([d['nr'],d['data'])
```